# Mounting a RAM disk on startup, but seems to be unmounted automatically

Tags: hard-drive, memory, disk-utility, mount

I wrote a simple script that mounts a ram disk:

```
%> cat /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ramdisk.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>Ramdisk</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/setup_run_shm</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But when I logged in, the disk is gone. It looks like the disk is unmounted. 
I'm not really sure why. According to `/tmp/log.1` there's no errors.

P.S attached the setup_run_shm script:

```
%> cat /usr/local/bin/setup_run_shm
#!/bin/bash

exec &> /tmp/log.1
date
set -x

size=$(( 1024*1024*8 ))
path=/run/shm/
name="SHM"

if mount | grep -q '/run/shm'; then
    echo RAM disk already exist.
    echo 'Eject the disk and try again. (e.g hdiutil eject /dev/diskX)'
    exit
fi

disk=$(hdiutil attach -nomount ram://"$size")
echo Attached RAM disk $disk

newfs_hfs -v "$name" $disk
echo Formatted RAM disk with name $name

mount -t hfs $disk "$path"
echo Mounted ram disk of size $size to $path
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure whether this is truly an answer to your question, but this Applescript works for me, run as an App.

```
set RAMDisk to "RAM_Disk" as text
tell application "Finder"
    if not {exists disk RAMDisk} then
        set VolumeName to RAMDisk
        set SizeInMB to 1024
        set NumSectors to ((2 * 1024 * SizeInMB))
        set DeviceName to do shell script "hdid -nomount ram://" & NumSectors
        do shell script "diskutil eraseVolume 'HFS+' '" & VolumeName & "' " & DeviceName
        do shell script "SetFile -a V /Volumes/" & VolumeName       
    end if  
end tell
```

It needs Developer Command Line Tools installed to run, but will ask & auto-install if not present.

Comment: It must be started at boot. My script works but not sure why it's reverted ....

Comment: ahh… at login is too late for your purposes? Sorry, was only an idea.